# Is it possible to describe an event tensed ambiguously?

Tags: tenses

If an event will occur in the future I might say:

```
There will be an event and it will have a number of features.
```

If it occurs in the past I might say:

```
There was an event and it had a number of features.
```

If it is occurring now I might say:

```
There is an event and it has a number of features.
```

What if I dont yet know the time of the event relative to "now"? Alternatively, what if I do not want to reveal if the event has occurred yet, but I do want want to describe it?

If I want to remain ambiguous about gender I can use the neuter form. Is there something equivilent in tense, or is there a selection of tense neutral words I can use instead?

Comment: Nominalize it _the occurrence of this event_ or use a tenseless verb construction like gerund _having this event_ or infinitive _to  make this event happen_, etc.

Comment: "The Simple Present can also indicate the speaker believes that a fact was true before, is true now, and will be true in the future." http://www.englishpage.com/images/verbs/simplepresentfact.gif http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html

Comment: I believe that there are sufficient people who are infuriated with my explanation of the subjunctive - but subjunctive is what you actually mean. What you mean is not *ambiguous*, but *encapsulated* for flexibility. Read my response at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155893/how-is-the-english-subjunctive-composed/156033#156033.

Answer (score 1):

A generalization like one of these doesn't specify when the event occurs:

> There are a number of features with this event.

or

> There are a number of features associated with this event.

or

> The event is associated with a number of features.

Comment: There **is** a number of features ....

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck: [Do the math.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/singular_plural_number.htm) :)