# How to refer to an event happening without referring to when it's happening?

Tags: tenses, time

I can say that an event **will** happen, or **has** happened, or **is** happening. But is there a way to say that an event exists in the time line without referring to WHEN it is placed?

For example, I can say `I ate`, `I am eating`, and `I will eat`. But how can I say in a single word `Of all the events that have happened and will happen to me, eating is included in them`?

Comment: Could you make yourself a bit more clear by including a sample sentence, perhaps?

Comment: this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159890/is-it-possible-to-describe-an-event-tensed-ambiguously?rq=1 implies that there is no one single word to describe an event in the timeline existing. You have to phrase it with some awkward phrase.

Comment: The infinitive tense is a way to refer to a verb without implying a placement in time. I think you answered your own question with the gerund you chose: "My lifetime includes eating."

Comment: Depending on what it is you want to do with this, you may be able to do something with an agent noun (or similar): *I am an eater*.

Comment: Also, consider the present-tense-used-timelessly: "S--t happens."

Comment: By the way, this seems like resurrecting an old question by asking it again. We want to avoid duplicate questions; in the future, if you find a question with an insufficient answer, you can give your own answer, or leave a comment bringing it to others' attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to describe an event tensed ambiguously?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159890/is-it-possible-to-describe-an-event-tensed-ambiguously)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @AndyBonner. That question poped up after I had posted this one. Next time this happens, I can close my own question as duplicate and link to the other one?