# How to express the fact that clauses in a compound logical statement are connected by "AND"?

Tags: expressions, mathematics, logic

Say, I have three independent logical clauses, a, b, and c, and they are connected into one logical statement (a∧b∧c).  How do I express this succinctly?  Can I say, "a, b, and c are connected conjunctively?"  I don't seem to get many hits for that construct on Google.

(This is a question about English language and usage, albeit in a very specific field, mathematical logics.  I hope it's still on topic, here.)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you asking for a linguistic terminology or a for examples of syntax?

Comment: I'm asking for an expression.

Comment: The more specialised the field, the less likely there is to be an everyday expression to cover any specific situation in an adequate (well-defined) way. // Surely, in logic, 'John is tall, Ali is clever, and Betty is pretty' would be analysed as three independent statements (truth values 0, 1 and 1, perhaps)? Once you start using the logical and operator, you're outside the scope of everyday English; 'and' is not really the same English word any more. Though the term 'conjunction' is apparently used in the new sense also [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)].

Comment: They are *conjuncted* -- though I would rather say they are *anded*, which's perfectly legal, simpler and makes the reader's life all that much easier.

Comment: To add to @Kris, and be more specific, putting a tiny bit more emphasis on and(AND) can make it work even better. "A, b, and c are AND-ed".

Comment: There is *sequential/subsequence dependency* AND, vs *adjuct mutually independent events* AND, vs *conjuct shared-attribute* AND. *Sequential/subsequence dependency* AND can be either bayesian-subsequence subjunctive, or stative subsequence.

Comment: Pls specify which AND you are desiring to engage in. Or all of them.

Comment: Also take note of demorgan's resolution which states that (1) {not A} AND {not B} = not {A OR B}. (2) {not A} OR {not B} = not {A AND B}.

Comment: Also consider stating for the case of {A AND B AND C}, whether A, B. C are the exclusive members of an event set, or are just a pick of a larger unspecified number of members event-set.

Comment: @BlessedGeek : I'm looking for the simple, propositional logic case, though I seriously doubt that it makes any difference for the verbalization of the formula.  And since I'm talking about logics, not probability, I can't see how anything Bayesian may be related.  Furthermore, I do know de Morgan's laws, but what do they have to do with my question?

Comment: Bayesian subsequence can be boolean. Many subjuctive cases are bayesian subsequence. Bayesian is the subsequence dependency of events. Bayesian logic and Bayesian probability are the derivative subjects of bayesian events.

Comment: My take on bayesian subjunctive : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155893/how-is-the-english-subjunctive-composed/156033#156033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say that **a, b and c form a conjunction**.

Although one might say that the conjunction is just the word *and* in that sentence, the word can also be used to refer to (a∧b∧c) as a whole.

Here is an example from a book in a relevant field:

, *Symbolic Logic* by Hardegree, page 104:

> ... the statement,
>   `(c) Jay and Kay are Sophomores,`
>   is equivalent to the conjunction,
>   `Jay is a Sophomore, and Kay is a Sophomore,`
>   and is accordingly symbolized
>   `J & K`
>   [- Hardegree, pp103-104, Symbolic Logic](http://courses.umass.edu/phil110-gmh/text/c04_3-99.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Just say
"All of these<sup>1</sup> conditions<sup>2</sup> are<sup>3</sup> true."
________
<sup>1</sup> Or "the above" or "the below", as applicable.
<sup>2</sup> Or "statements".
<sup>3</sup> Or "must be".